# statically compile an android program

Tags: linker, android-ndk, arm

i'm trying to write something into the dmesg log before /system being mounted.
my trouble is that for write into dmesg ( on android ) i need to use the android-specific stuff, not just my usually crossdev arm system.
just:

```
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "libnav", "DEBUG - custom program started");
```

all fine if you compile it as follow ( i make a standalone toolchain in /var/tmp/android ):

```
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot /var/tmp/android/sysroot -llog -o custom_program custom_program.c
```

BUT the above command will build a dynamically linked executable, which will run fine if system is yet booted up.
"easy, just compile it statically!" i thought.
the android ndk comes with some libs  but the liblog is only liblog.so, not liblog.a, so how can i log something in dmesg before /system beign mounted ?
thanks in advance.

Comment: You should accept answers or provide comments.

Answer (score 0):

Using arm-unknown-gnueabi-gcc and
fopen the /dev/kmsg and fprintf on the FILE * returned by fopen.
running the program while android is running will write into dmesg, but not if in early boot process. why?

@auselen
i yet have modified init to startup this static program:
init.rc snippet

```
on post-fs-data
write /dev/kmsg "launching test"
exec /data/test
```

all i see in dmesg is this...

```
<4>[    6.336816] launching test
<6>[    6.336902] init: command 'write' r=0
<6>[    6.337115] init: command 'exec' r=-1
```

here you are the executable source code: http://pastebin.com/Hym1APWx

Comment: You should create separate questions for separate concerns. This not an answer to your own question btw.

Comment: It may not be possible to run it from data partition.

Comment: yes, i did, i thought that was right answering to you, since you answer to me ;)  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070212/executing-static-program-from-android-init-rc

Comment: it's possible when andoid is running...why not in the early-boot phase?