# executing static program from android init.rc

Tags: android, initialization

I want to start a custom program in the `init` process. I compiled this program statically that run fine from my booted up android stock ROM.

From the android `init.rc` docs I read that the `exec` command is what I need.
BTW all I can see in `dmesg` is that my program exit with code `-1` (I can't return that).

`init.rc` snippet:

```
on post-fs-data
write /dev/kmsg "launching test"
exec /data/test
```

All I see in `dmesg` is this:

```
<4>[    6.336816] launching test
<6>[    6.336902] init: command 'write' r=0
<6>[    6.337115] init: command 'exec' r=-1
```

Here you are the executable source code: http://pastebin.com/Hym1APWx

---

#### UPDATE

I tried to statically compile and run this program:

```
int main(){return 0; }
```

But the result is always `command 'exec' r=-1`. Maybe user **uselen** are right, maybe I cannot run executables from `/data` in the early-boot phase.

Comment: why you are hacking the boot process, just register for broadcast onBootComplete and do what ever you want.

Comment: @Anis i want to chroot into a custom directory, then import a custom init.rc and go forward.
i'm doing this for have a dual-boot, so i can't wait the android default boot, since i want to boot-up with linux.

Comment: I would just try with a simple helloworld.

Comment: If you want to avoid starting android just don't start system service.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As christian said, it looks like exec isn't even implemented. I'm beginning to think that a lot of features documented for init.rc aren't implemented. Here's a way you can get your program to launch however.

Instead of running this as an "exec" command, set this up as a service instead.

In your init.rc, or another file included by it:

```
service my_service /data/test
    class main
    oneshot
```

If it's in class main, and not disabled, it should run after /data is mounted.

Comment: sorry if a didn't share my knowledge, i found this workaround much time ago. thanks anyway ;)

Comment: Wish I would have found this sooner.  Would have saved hours of trying to make exec work.

Comment: What do you mean by "If it's in class main" ?!

Comment: An important thing to note was that this will not run on the first ever boot (after a flash or a factory reset). I had a lot of attempts thinking my code was failing or wrong when actually it was just not running on the first boot.

Comment: "class main" means that it's run when "class_start main" happens in another init section.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue today. In my case the solution was simple: The `exec` function wasn't implemented yet and contained just a `return -1`. You should take a look at `builtin.c` and search for `do_exec()`. This code is executed when `init.rc` contains an `exec` statement.

Comment: It has been implemented in [current master](https://github.com/android/platform_system_core/commit/8d82ea05cb0945ba6cb8bf321b9ffbd0b6932745), in file [init/builtins.cpp](https://github.com/android/platform_system_core/blob/master/init/builtins.cpp). The question is when it's going to be integrated - the whole init is rewritten from C to C++.